# launch file to make rviz to subscribe to laserscan published from a bag file

Tags: ros, rviz, roslaunch, bagfile, laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

how can I make rviz to display laserscan data played from a bag file using a launch file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/70168/launch-file-to-make-rviz-to-subscribe-to-laserscan-published-from-a-bag-file/) by [Solmaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/2778/solmaz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-07-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Solmaz,

you should first run everything and set that up as you like. Once your rviz looks just as you want, save the configuration file of rviz and pass it with argument '-d' to your rviz node instance in your launchfile. This way, your rviz will look always the same.

---

Originally posted by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) with karma: 1471 on 2013-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0